# Formula to Detect Certain Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel that looks like this:

[image]

I need a formula that will prompt 'NOK' (or 'OK') when the size is not with the range (Lowest & Highest). The expected output should looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For O2, your formula would be:

```
=IF(AND(L2<=M2, L2>=M2),"OK","NOK")
```

and of course, you can drag it down for all other cells under column O